# How to convert only row matrices in a list to column matrices in R?

Tags: r, list, matrix, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have a list of matrices where most of the matrices are column matrices but some of them are row matrices. How to convert only those row matrices to column matrices? I would like to achieve this using base R.

Here is the list of matrices where the third one is a row matrix

```
x <- list(`1` = matrix(1:20, nrow=5), `2` = matrix(1:20, nrow=10), `3` = matrix(1:5, nrow=1))
```

How to convert the list to one like this:

```
$`1`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10

$`2`
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10

$`3`
[1,]    1    
[2,]    2    
[3,]    3   
[4,]    4    
[5,]    5
```

I have a much larger dataset and so efficient code is preferred!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the dimensions of the matrix and transpose it if the row dimension is 1:

```
(y <- lapply(x, function(x) if(dim(x)[1] == 1) { t(x)} else x))
# $`1`
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    6   11   16
# [2,]    2    7   12   17
# [3,]    3    8   13   18
# [4,]    4    9   14   19
# [5,]    5   10   15   20
# 
# $`2`
#       [,1] [,2]
#  [1,]    1   11
#  [2,]    2   12
#  [3,]    3   13
#  [4,]    4   14
#  [5,]    5   15
#  [6,]    6   16
#  [7,]    7   17
#  [8,]    8   18
#  [9,]    9   19
# [10,]   10   20
# 
# $`3`
#      [,1]
# [1,]    1
# [2,]    2
# [3,]    3
# [4,]    4
# [5,]    5
```

Comment: Thank you @dcarlson. This did work for my example data here. One more question though. When I checked the condition in `if` using `dim(x)[1] == 1`, it showed `logical(0)`. Isn't it supposed to single out the elements that fit the condition?

Comment: Yes, but within `function(x)` inside `lapply()`, the `x` represents each of the matrices in your list `x`, i.e. `x[[1]]`, `x[[2]]`, x[[3]]`. Since your `x` is a list, `dim(x)` is NULL. I should have used a different argument in the function to make this clearer, e.g. `function(y) if(dim(y)[1] == 1) { t(y)} else y)`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!